# SQL Joining table to itself with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have one table and I want to GROUP BY it by ID but at the same time I want to create another GROUP BY with ID and DATE and then join this table to table with ID grouping. Example code:

Here is how to tables are created and I want to LEFT JOIN TEMP to ORG with ID and [DATE] to get FIRST and LAST on ORG table.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MIN([DATE]) AS MIN_DATE,
FROM [ORG] AS ORG
GROUP BY ID
    
SELECT
    ID, 
    [DATE],
    MIN(EXEC_AS_OF_TIME) AS [FIRST],
    MAX(EXEC_AS_OF_TIME) AS [LAST]
FROM [ORG] AS TEMP
GROUP BY ID, [DATE]
```

Here is how I thought it would work, but it doesn't. Where I'm going wrong here?

```
SELECT
    ORG.ID,
    MIN([ORG.DATE]) AS MIN_DATE,
    TEMP.[FIRST],
    TEMP.[LAST]
FROM [ORG] AS ORG
GROUP BY ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        ID, 
        [DATE],
        MIN(EXEC_AS_OF_TIME) AS [FIRST],
        MAX(EXEC_AS_OF_TIME) AS [LAST]
    FROM [TEMP]
    GROUP BY ID, [DATE]
) AS TEMP ON ORG.ID = TEMP.ID AND ORG.[MIN_DATE] = TEMP.[DATE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the syntax like the below -

```
select org.id, MIN_DATE,FIRST,LAST
from
(
SELECT ORG.ID,MIN([ORG.DATE]) AS MIN_DATE
FROM [ORG] GROUP BY ID) AS ORG
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ID, [DATE],
    MIN(EXEC_AS_OF_TIME) AS [FIRST],MAX(EXEC_AS_OF_TIME) AS [LAST]
FROM [ORG]
GROUP BY ID, [DATE]) AS TEMP ON ORG.ID = TEMP.ID AND ORG.[MIN_DATE] = TEMP.[DATE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need such a complicated query for this.  Just use a window function:

```
SELECT id.*
FROM (SELECT ID, [DATE],
             MIN(EXEC_AS_OF_TIME) AS [FIRST],
             MAX(EXEC_AS_OF_TIME) AS [LAST],
             MIN([DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as MIN_DATE
      FROM [ORG] AS TEMP
      GROUP BY ID, [DATE]
     ) id
WHERE [DATE] = min_date;
```